# Why wont my array element update when using this nested for loop?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I'm a beginner following an online course, and in this course I have the challenge of making a console Tic-Tac-Toe game from scratch. I've decided to go with a 2D array to store the "plots" of the game grid. To cycle through the array in order to compare the player input against the array elements I have chosen a nested for loop which seems to work fine. It identifies the correct element that matches with the player input, but for some reason I cant update the particular element. I hope this makes sense.

I've not tried much else other than to use a foreach loop, but I cant figure out how to get it to iterate properly through a multidimensional array.

```
string[,] myArray = { { "1", "2", "3", }, { "4", "5", "6" }, { "7", "8", 
"9" } };

     Console.WriteLine("Player 1's go - enter a number to place your turn");
        string playerInput = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            int parsedInput = Int32.Parse(playerInput);
            if (parsedInput > 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Only enter a number that is in use on the game screen");
                PlayerTurn(myArray);
            }

        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please input the correct format");
            PlayerTurn(myArray);
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Only enter a number you can see on the game screen");
            PlayerTurn(myArray);
        }

 for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < myArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (playerInput == myArray[i,j])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(myArray[i,j]); // this is to check 
                                          //that the if statement is working (which it is)

                        myArray[i, j] = "X"; // this isnt working correctly

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

When the player presses the 1 key, I expect the myArray[0,0] element to change from "1" to "X" but nothing happens.

Comment: Your iteration looks correct, and I agree that it should work. But, can you add how you are getting `playerInput` in to the program and how you are coming to the conclusion that the assignment to `x` doesn't work, please?

Comment: How did you check that it doesn't work corectly? If I trace `Console.WriteLine(myArray[i,j]);` right after `myArray[i, j] = "X"; ` it'll show X as expected.

Comment: @JayV I have edited the post to include my player input code

Comment: @obscure Im checking it in run time. If I enter "1" The element in question is still holding the "1" instead of the X. If that makes sense. I just tried what you have done and the code is working and is storing "X" but its not updating this on my grid

Comment: Are you by any chance reinitialize `myArray` in your code? Try making it a global variable and see the result.

Comment: @byteSized I think you should include your whole program, if it isn't too big. I am inclined to think that the problem may be related to how/where you output the grid to the players. The code fragment works, so it suggests the problem is in other logic of your game.

Comment: @byteSized if you put the line `Console.WriteLine(myArray[i,j]);` after you do `myArray[i, j] = "X";` in the nested loop, you will see the problem is not in this section of code

Comment: @JayV Thanks, but with your collective help I've been able to identify the problem. I have the grid in one method and the player input in another method and I wasn't updating the grid method with the new player input information.

Answer (score 0):

I think your PlayerTurn method's body is the code block you posted. Each call of PlayerTurn initialize myArray with given value again and again. You should locate myArray variable outside PlayerTurn